# Recreating the scroll position of Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

We have a collapsing toolbarlayout and RecyclerView in the CoordinatorLayout. 
The Collapsing toolbarlayout is in expanded state. When the user scrolls the view the Collapsingtoolbarlayout scrolls too along with recyclerview. 
Basically, if the user scrolls the screen, I would like to recreate the same state of the screen programmatically in the other screen. Can anyone let me know what should be saved from the layout saved state to recreate the same scroll position of the entire screen i.e the same scroll position of CollapsingToolbar and RecyclerView i.e. the screen should look absolutely same as it was in the previous screen.

Comment: Any Suggestions ?